# Why is R not ordering my tibble in the correct order?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataframe with two columns that I need to arrange in chronological order and then combine. R is strangely placing the integer 100 just after 10. I can't figure out how to stop this behavior.

Here is a reprex example.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(x = 0:100, 
       y = sample(0:100, 101, T)) 


df_i <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), 
         z = glue('{x}.{y}'))

df_i %>% 
  arrange(z)

# A tibble: 101 x 4
       x     y    id z     
   <int> <int> <int> <glue>
 1     0    30     1 0.30  
 2     1    78     2 1.78  
 3    10    24    11 10.24 
 4   100    22   101 100.22
 5    11    89    12 11.89 
 6    12    90    13 12.90 
 7    13    68    14 13.68 
 8    14    90    15 14.90 
 9    15    56    16 15.56 
10    16    91    17 16.91 
# … with 91 more rows
```

You can see that the fourth row is not in the correct order. It looks like the `x` and `y` columns are not in order either. I feel like this is something trivial but it's causing some sneaky problems.

Comment: Your `z` column is not numeric. If you want it ordered as a number, you must make it a number. Try changing the definition to `z = as.numeric(glue(...))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'z' is a `glue` object (and according to `?glue` - `Format and interpolate a string`, so it would be a string output) and it needs to be converted to `numeric`

```
df_i %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(z))
```

If we check the `glue` source code, it calls `glue_data` which in turn calls `as_glue` and checking the `as_glue` it converts to `character`

```
methods('as_glue')
getAnywhere('as_glue.default')
#function (x, ...) 
#{
#    as_glue(as.character(x))
#}
```

---

The behaviour is similar to `sort`ing a `character` vector of numbers

```
sort(c('1', '2', '10', '20', '100'))
#[1] "1"   "10"  "100" "2"   "20"
```